# Call to a member function isCollection() on null

Tags: php, symfony, neo4j, graphaware, neo4j-php-ogm

I, using the Graphaware Neo4j-php-OGM. I would like to access the 2nd level relationship. I can't seen to get it to work. What am i doing wrong?

I'm trying to execute the following:

```
public function allowToContinue($userUuid, $permissionUuid)
    {
        $userRepo = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class);
        $permRoleRepo = $this->entityManager->getRepository(PermRole::class);
        $permissionRepo = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Permission::class);
        $user = $userRepo->findOneBy(['uuid' => $userUuid]);
        $permission = $permissionRepo->findOneBy(['uuid' => $permissionUuid]);
        $allowed = false;
        foreach ($user->getPermrole() as $userRole)
        {
            var_dump($userRole);
            $role = $permRoleRepo->findOneBy(['uuid' => $userRole->getUuid()]);
            var_dump($role);
            foreach ($role->getPermissions() as $perm)
            {
                var_dump($perm->getUuid());
                if($perm->getUuid() === $permissionUuid){
                    $allowed = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return $allowed;
    }
```

Stacktrace:

```
Error:
Call to a member function isCollection() on null

  at vendor/graphaware/neo4j-php-ogm/src/Hydrator/EntityHydrator.php:107
  at GraphAware\Neo4j\OGM\Hydrator\EntityHydrator->hydrateSimpleRelationshipCollection('permissions', object(Result), object(neo4j_ogm_proxy_App_Entity_Generic_PermRole))
     (vendor/graphaware/neo4j-php-ogm/src/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php:104)
  at GraphAware\Neo4j\OGM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister->getSimpleRelationshipCollection('permissions', object(neo4j_ogm_proxy_App_Entity_Generic_PermRole))
     (vendor/graphaware/neo4j-php-ogm/src/Proxy/NodeCollectionInitializer.php:22)
  at GraphAware\Neo4j\OGM\Proxy\NodeCollectionInitializer->initialize(object(Node), object(neo4j_ogm_proxy_App_Entity_Generic_PermRole))
     (vendor/graphaware/neo4j-php-ogm/src/Proxy/LazyCollection.php:52)
  at GraphAware\Neo4j\OGM\Proxy\LazyCollection->doInitialize()
     (vendor/doctrine/collections/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/AbstractLazyCollection.php:332)
  at Doctrine\Common\Collections\AbstractLazyCollection->initialize()
     (vendor/doctrine/collections/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/AbstractLazyCollection.php:274)
  at Doctrine\Common\Collections\AbstractLazyCollection->getIterator()
     (src/Security/RoleChecker.php:45)
  at App\Security\RoleChecker->allowToContinue('8d88d920-5ab0-11e8-a371-001c42dff143', 'd93370b0-585d-11e8-a371-001c42dff143')
     (src/Controller/Generic/UserController.php:146)
  at App\Controller\Generic\UserController->destroy('c34f1380-5ab5-11e8-a371-001c42dff143')
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:149)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:66)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:188)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (public/index.php:37)
```

It throws the error on the 2nd foreach loop on line:

`foreach ($role->getPermissions() as $perm)`

It's strange, working the first time correctly and not the 2nd time. Also after fetching the object again to be sure. Without this it throws the exact same notice.
Thanks in advance!

All code is at github: https://github.com/djkevino/Support4Neo

Comment: Suggests to me that one of the roles has nothing assigned in terms of permissions. Is that a valid state? Error is clear, can't execute the method on a null. What jumped out at me actually is not breaking the loop on `$allowed = true;`. Would you not at that point want to exit the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, pretty confused by this code. The `var_dump() die()` stuff in `destroy()`... Also, took me a while to realize we are talking about code in the library, not your code that interacts with this library.

Can you avoid the issue like so?

```
//add this next line
if (!is_iterable($user->getPermrole())) continue;
foreach ($role->getPermissions() as $perm)
```

If you are not on PHP version 7.1 or greater you could simply check if the returned value `is_null` or test for `instance of \Traversable` and `is_array`...

```
is_array($foo) || (is_object($foo) && ($foo instanceof \Traversable ));
```

As stated in my comment, not sure if that role having no "permissions" is considered a valid state or not.

Answer (score 1):

1. It looks like $role->getPermissions() can return a `null` result. So, make sure  the result is not `null` before executing the inner `foreach` loop.
2. Since you seem to be testing if *any* of the user's roles has the desired permission, you do not need the `$allowed` variable at all. The inner `foreach` loop can just immediately return `true` once a match is found, avoiding unnecessary processing.

That is, try this:

```
public function allowToContinue($userUuid, $permissionUuid) {
    $userRepo = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class);
    $permRoleRepo = $this->entityManager->getRepository(PermRole::class);
    $permissionRepo = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Permission::class);
    $user = $userRepo->findOneBy(['uuid' => $userUuid]);
    $permission = $permissionRepo->findOneBy(['uuid' => $permissionUuid]);        
    foreach ($user->getPermrole() as $userRole) {
        var_dump($userRole);
        $role = $permRoleRepo->findOneBy(['uuid' => $userRole->getUuid()]);
        var_dump($role);
        $rolePerms = $role->getPermissions();
        if (!is_null($rolePerms)) {
            foreach ($rolePerms as $perm) {
                var_dump($perm->getUuid());
                if ($perm->getUuid() === $permissionUuid) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```